# How to move a Grid Panel in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, move

HI,

How do I move (drag) a Grid Panel inside a WPF Window? The Grid Panel does not have a Position or Location or X and Y coordinate porperty. All I am looking at is to move the Grid Panel from its current location to a new location using Mouse so that the controls that are "burried" underneath it will show up.

Any pointers?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's some code examples to get you started:

In XAML:

Create a grid and define a render transform on it:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Blue" 
      Width="100" Height="100" 
      MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

Name the control that you want the grid to move within:

```
<Window x:Name="window" ...>
    <Grid x:Name="grid"...
</Window>
```

In code behind:

```
Point m_start;
Vector m_startOffset;

private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_start = e.GetPosition(window);
    m_startOffset = new Vector(tt.X, tt.Y);
    grid.CaptureMouse();
}

private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.IsMouseCaptured)
    {
        Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(window), m_start);

        tt.X = m_startOffset.X + offset.X;
        tt.Y = m_startOffset.Y + offset.Y;
    }
}

private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    grid.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```

Comment: Nice, But This approach is not very efficient. When dragging a grid containing about 10 custom template controls, my CPU load goes up to 23%! (Core i7 3770) Isn't there a better way of doing that? I also changed the parent container to canvas and used `Canvas.SetLeft`, but no performance change.

Comment: Render transforms are expensive, especially when you are dynamically re-rendering a really complex control. There's no simple way around that. A few suggestions: Create a simpler copy of the control (or even save a snapshot of the image) and use this copy for the drag / drop render transform. OR: Don't update the render transform every time the mouse moves. Update it every Nth hit, or only when the offset is greater than a certain threshold, or only after timed intervals, etc.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll just check the user's graphics rendering tier and move just a snapshot of the control when the system isn't tier 2.

Comment: I implemented a 3D flip view once using this method and it was really seamless. Don't have the code available at the moment, but that was exactly what it did. Save the control as an image and then hide the control and display the image. perform all of the transforms on the image until the animation / operation is complete and then hide the image and display the actual control again so that you can interact with the nested inputs.

Answer (score 3):

***Based on Josh G's answer***

Josh's answer is excellent if you want to move one grid, but lacks capabilities for movement of several elements.
This is how to move several elements separately

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="gridHost">
    <Grid x:Name="gridBlue" Background="Blue" Width="100" Height="100" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp" Margin="-100,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gridRed" Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp" Margin="100,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
Point m_start;
    Vector m_startOffset;

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as Grid;
        TranslateTransform translate = element.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;

        m_start = e.GetPosition(gridHost);
        m_startOffset = new Vector(translate.X, translate.Y);
        element.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as Grid;
        TranslateTransform translate = element.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;

        if (element.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(gridHost), m_start);

            translate.X = m_startOffset.X + offset.X;
            translate.Y = m_startOffset.Y + offset.Y;
        }
    }

    private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as Grid;
        element.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the grid panel inside a canvas rather than directly into the window - this will then give it X/Y co-ordinates.

You can then implement the drag/drop behaviour using a custom attached property such as detailed here (http://www.deepcode.co.uk/archive/2008/11/16/using-attached-properties-to-compose-new-behaviour.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void dragme(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Move.IsChecked == true)
            db.Attach((DependencyObject)sender);
```

}

//// MouseDragElementBehavior db;

```
 private void canvass_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    {
if (_Move.IsChecked == true && filmgrid.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)// == true)  
            {
                filmgrid.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(dragme); 
            }
```

}